# How to find similar rows in columns with difflib?

Tags: python

Please, I have two CSV files with columns with company names. With Python3 and pandas I made a merge to compare the names:

```
compara1 = pd.merge(
    dividas_dep, funrural,
    left_on='Nome_Devedor',
    right_on='Razao_Social')
```

Found seven rows with equal columns. But these files have company names that are not always correctly typed in some of the files. Example:

```
AGROPECUARIA INDIANA LTDA
AGROPECUARIA INDINA LTDA

AGROTRI AGROPECUARIA TRIANGULO LTDA
AGROTRI AGROPECUARI TRIANGULO LTDA
```

So the merge does not find similar values In Python

I then used difflib:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    threshold = 0.8
    return (SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > threshold)


for i, row in dividas_dep.iterrows():
    a = (row['Nome_Devedor'])
    for i, row in funrural.iterrows():
        b = (row['Razao_Social'])
        similar(a, b)
```

Processed for about 5 minutes but did not return anything. Something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it only needed to show the result, I realized now:

```
def similar(a, b):
    threshold = 0.8
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > threshold
    print(s)
    return s


for i, row in dividas_dep.iterrows():
    a = (row['Nome_Devedor'])
    for i, row in funrural.iterrows():
        b = (row['Razao_Social'])
        similar(a, b)
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print("-/-")
```