# Logic used for this string pattern matching script for use with in a df column

Tags: python, string-matching

I have df with the following columns:

`['Date', 'Company Name', Amount]`

under `Company Name` however, there are cases in which one company has a similar name to another company; eg. `'Acme Corporation' vs 'Acme Corpor'` which are the exact same company.

to be more specific about the df, here is a sample below:

```
['Date', 'Company Name',  'Amount']
['01/01',    'ACME',         100  ]
['01/01', 'ACME Corpor',     150  ]
['01/01', 'ACME Corpor',     150  ]
['01/02', 'ACME Corporation', 50  ]
```

which of course spans other dates and a total of 2500+ *unique* companies

what I need is (for example) to turn ACME Corpor into ACME Corporation without affecting ACME (based on the sample df above)

I have already built up some sort of logic to do this but I think that my overall script is inefficient or just faulty.

I based my logic on the following block of code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

which I took from this: [How to find similar rows in columns with difflib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711982/how-to-find-similar-rows-in-columns-with-difflib)

so basically I match two items together (`a` and `b`) within the `Company Name` column and decide an arbitrary threshold (Which I set to 0.7 for this example) if the result of the matching is above 0.7, then I append `a` to a new column (Say `new_names`), if not then I append `b`.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

new_name = []

for i in range(0,len(df.company)-1):
    if (similar(df.company[i],df.company[i+1]) > 0.7) & (i != 0):
        new_name.append(df.customer[i])
    else:
        new_name.append(df.customer[i+1])
```

Nothing really happens with this which I assume is due to the repetition that happens within the 'Company Name' column. I've tried using the block of code above to a grouped data frame which works fine I believe but as much as possible I want to be using the script on the `"raw"` df

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any kind of list which contains all your desirable names of companies? Like in your example it would be:

`desire_names = ['ACME', 'ACME_Corporation']`

If yes then you can measure distances of all strings from 'Company Name' to desire_names by e.g Levenshtein distance. That might be helpful [row to row distance measure in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892617/edit-distance-between-two-pandas-columns). That's pretty computational costly if your desire_names list is long, cause you have to measure distances between all 'Company Names' strings and desire_names strings.

If you you've got dictionary like

`desire_names = {'ACME': 'ACME', 'ACME_CORP': 'ACME_CORPORATION', 'ACME_CORPORATION': 'ACME_CORPORATION'}`

Then you can just use df.replace function.

Comment: Sadly I don't think we have a list of those companies on hand but sure I can confirm and take note of that link you've attached. I guess with that I can just get the unique items in the 'Company Name' column and just make one myself... I can save this as a backup plan as we are really pressed for time. Thanks!